# Selection issue in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have order rows that I need to choose according to transcodes.

```
Order#    Transacodes
123           CVC
123           ABC
123           GRE
123           DEF
```

I want those order rows that have both CVC and GRE.

I tried doing this with in ("CVC" "GRE" ) but this gives me those with only one of the codes, whilst I need both.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [Order#] IN (
    SELECT [Order#] 
    FROM table
    WHERE Transcodes = 'CVC'
    )
AND [Order#] IN (
    SELECT [Order#] 
    FROM table
    WHERE Transcodes = 'GRE'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
select order#
from t
where transacodes in ('CVC', 'GRE')
group by order#
having count(distinct transacodes) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select order#
from orders
where Transacodes in  ('CVC','GRE') 
group by order#
having count(distinct Transacodes) = 2;
```